# this is probably a dumb question

Tags: software, hardware, nuendo4, omf

Does nuendo4 work on the icore7 macbook pro properly? I have been having a few problems with it. For instance when I import an omf, the sounds are all squashed together and out of sync, when I import i select the timecode position option and it still goes out of sync?

Is nuendo 4 compatable with my mac book pro or not and if it isnt I will sort it out thanks

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer your question regarding i7, but maybe I can help with the OMF issue.

If there is no burnt in timecode and you select "at time code position" when importing the OMFs, you'll have that issue. Try selecting "at absolute time" and see if that fixes your problem.

Another reason why you might be having this issue is because of a bug between Final Cut Pro and Nuendo. Is your OMF coming from FCP? If so, you need to upgrade to the latest Nuendo and it should work. I had this issue last year and if my memory is correct, the update had to come from Nuendo.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes yes YES! it could be that the timecode isnt burnt into the omf or i will need to upgrade by that you mean nuendo5??? or can i just download upgrades from the site? thanks guys but i did import it as absolute time it helped thanks mr spitz

Comment: @Jm Not N5, I mean Nuendo 4.3. Hope you get it working!

Answer (score 0):

Whether you're on an i7 or a Core Duo it is still an Intel and Mac OS is just an interface between your hardware and the piece of software you're trying to run, so much so that this piece of software is always presented with the same resources and the same methods to use them (just like driving a car, you've always got a steering wheel and pedals that are presented identically from car to car). If Nuendo works on an Intel Mac, it works on all Intel Macs until they dramatically change of architecture. That was for the geeky bit.

Now, about Nuendo itself. Rather, I would imagine your problem to be **related to your specific install** (if you do a **clean install** you will see more clearly what options you have left, I don't know how painful the process can be with Nuendo...). Before you do that, just make sure all OMF's are unusable and that it's **not a problem with one particular OMF** file.

Also I don't know if you've already come across [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tHgZQxJPeFA), but **OMF's seem to be problematic** with Nuendo 4.

Comment: thanks man, hmmm I see what you mean about omfs being problematic for nuendo 4 cos I have nuendo 3 on my pc and i tried it and it worked fine, nuendo 4 also tends to bug out on the mac a few times....

Answer (score 0):

I use Nuendo 4 on a new PC with the i7 chip and it works perfectly. If you are having trouble importing the OMF file double check with the video editor (or whomever gave you the OMF) and make sure they didn't mess it up on their end.  I find that I have to walk a lot of video editors through the correct process of exporting OMF files. I've never had any trouble with properly exported OMF files when importing into Nuendo.

Comment: thing is i never have problems on nuendo 3 (which is one my pc) but it seems nuendo 4 has problems with it. So i have imported the omf in it's time code position and ill re-sync it one nuendo 4, I did the 1st one by importing it in absolute time, the sound events are roughly in the right positions but i had to nudge them a few frames into place, so it's kinda crap but ill sort it out.